# Spring Cloud data flow does not show Spring cloud task execution details

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

The Spring cloud dataflow documentation mentions

> When executing tasks externally (i.e. command line) and you wish for Spring Cloud Data Flow to show the TaskExecutions in its UI, be sure that common datasource settings are shared among the both. By default Spring Cloud Task will use a local H2 instance and the execution will not be recorded to the database used by Spring Cloud Data Flow.

I am new to Spring cloud dataflow and spring cloud task. Can somebody help me how to setup a common datasource for both. For my development purpose I'm using the embedded H2 database. Can I use the embedded one to see task execution details in Spring Flo/Dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

A common "datasource" *must* be shared between Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) and your Spring Cloud Task (SCT) applications in order to track and monitor task executions. If the datasource is not shared, both SCDF and SCT applications by default use a **individual** H2 database. And because they are on different databases, the `task-executions` in SCDF won't have visibility to independent execution history of SCT microservice applications.

Make sure to supply common DB properties to both. In your case, you can supply the same H2 DB properties. It is as simple as Spring Boot DB property overrides.

Comment: Thanks @Sabby Anandan

Comment: Thanks so much Sabby - I was able to recover from the same error after pulling my hair for couple of hours.  I have it running now and posted my Project on my github too.