# Composed Task Runner doesn't show execution time

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I created a Composed Task Runner with below definition. SuccessTask and Notifier are simple Spring Cloud Task spring boot applications that are printing just Hello World and returning an exit code 0. When I create individual tasks I'm able to see the Start and End time; however when I combine them together I don't see the times. Please see the ID 4 below.

I have configured each separate task to point to the embedded H2 DB of spring cloud local dataflow server. Do I need to do something for the composed-task-runner as well? If so, how?

```
task create successFlow --definition "SuccessTask && Notifier"
task launch successFlow
task execution list

╔════════════╤══╤════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════╤═════════╗
║ Task Name  │ID│         Start Time         │          End Time          │Exit Code║
╠════════════╪══╪════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╪═════════╣
║failTest    │3 │Tue Oct 03 14:09:46 CDT 2017│Tue Oct 03 14:09:46 CDT 2017│1        ║
║notifierTest│2 │Tue Oct 03 14:07:10 CDT 2017│Tue Oct 03 14:07:10 CDT 2017│0        ║
║taskTest    │1 │Tue Oct 03 14:03:25 CDT 2017│Tue Oct 03 14:03:25 CDT 2017│0        ║
║successFlow │4 │                            │                            │0        ║
╚════════════╧══╧════════════════════════════╧════════════════════════════╧═════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

The similar [datasource requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496208/spring-cloud-data-flow-does-not-show-spring-cloud-task-execution-details) applies to composed-task-runner (CTR) as well. CTR embeds its own H2 DB instance by default, if you don't override it. We have clarified it in the docs via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#1640](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1640) recently.